# Jenkins When Clause not behaving as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Outline of question/issue

So the issue that we're facing is that even though PERSON is set to Mr Jenkins, and CC is only set to PERSON (thus Mr Jenkins) in the 'hello' block, so we expected the 'when test' block to run because it would reference the ("global") environment variable CC clang, and enter the stage, and then print "hello clang, this step ran". Instead, it printed "hello Mr Jenkins, this step ran". Which is confusing because in order to enter the stage, CC must be clang, but instead Mr Jenkins was printed in the echo statement.

Jenkins Pipeline Code:

```
pipeline{
        agent any
        environment{
            CC = 'clang'
        }
        parameters{
            string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')       
        }
        stages{

            stage('hello'){
                options{
                    timestamps()
                }
                steps{

                    script{
                        def output = PERSON
                        CC = output
                    }
                    echo "hello ${CC}"
                }
            }
            stage('when test'){
                when{
                    environment name: 'CC', value: 'clang'
                }
                steps{
                    echo "hello ${CC}, this step ran"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (hello)
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
17:18:09 hello Mr Jenkins
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (when test)
[Pipeline] echo
hello Mr Jenkins, this step ran
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Updating the when part to echo "hello " + env.CC + ", this step ran" gives the expected output but I have to admit I don't really know why your solution isn't working.

Comment: Try `env.CC = output` instead of `CC = output`. I'd expect that to fail. I guess the assignment you made is only valid within the stage or even the script block it happens in.
I am not sure about this, but I think the `environment` block is actually evaluated prior every stage, so any assignment is reverted.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, but neither of them seemed to work :( It seems that when a variable is created in a stage, it is persistent and globally accessible throughout the pipeline. When we tried env.CC, the value of environmental variable did not change at all. These are unexpected results, is this supposed to be normal behavior for Jenkins Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'when' block is working fine as their is an environment variable with name 'CC' and value 'clang', you just need to echo the right variable:

```
stage('when test'){
    when{
        environment name: 'CC', value: 'clang'
    }
    steps{
        echo "hello ${env.CC}, this step ran"
    }
}
```

**Another way to do it:**
As far as echoing ${CC} is concerned in 'when test' stage, you have declared a global variable previous stage and that is making it's presence felt here. You can also accomplish what you want to do, just by chainging your 'hello' stage:

```
stage('hello'){
    steps{

        script{
            output = PERSON
            //CC = output
        }
        echo "hello ${output}"
    }
}
stage('when test'){
    when{
        environment name: 'CC', value: 'clang'
    }
    steps{
        echo "hello ${CC}, this step ran"
    }
}
```